# Alert on only the 1st candle meeting the condition

Tags: pine-script

I have add an alert that when the 3ma are turning Green or Red to receive an alert.
But how can I only receive the alert once (when the 3 MAs are either all Green or all Red)and not on all candles meeting the condition.
And receive an alert when one of the 3 Mas change color.

Thank you for your help.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Moving Average Colored 3SMA/WMA', shorttitle='NGU-Shujie-Colored3SMA-WMA', overlay=true)
smaplot1 = input(true, title='Show SMA7 on chart')
len1 = input.int(7, minval=1, title='SMA Length')
src1 = close
out1 = ta.sma(src1, len1)
up1 = out1 > out1[1]
down1 = out1 < out1[1]
mycolor1 = up1 ? color.green : down1 ? color.red : color.blue
plot(out1 and smaplot1 ? out1 : na, title='SMA7', color=mycolor1, linewidth=2)

smaplot2 = input(false, title='Show SMA100 on chart')
len2 = input.int(100, minval=1, title='SMA Length')
src2 = close
out2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
up2 = out2 > out2[1]
down2 = out2 < out2[1]
mycolor2 = up2 ? color.rgb(251, 242, 110) : down2 ? color.rgb(251, 242, 110) : color.rgb(251, 242, 110)
plot(out2 and smaplot2 ? out2 : na, title='SMA100', color=mycolor2, linewidth=4)

wmaplot1 = input(false, title='Show WMA34 on chart')
len3 = input.int(34, minval=1, title='WMA Length')
src3 = close
out3 = ta.wma(src3, len3)
up3 = out3 > out3[1]
down3 = out3 < out3[1]
mycolor3 = up3 ? color.green : down3 ? color.red : color.blue
plot(out3 and wmaplot1 ? out3 : na, title='WMA34', color=mycolor3, linewidth=3)

wmaplot2 = input(false, title='Show WMA on chart')
len4 = input.int(20, minval=1, title='WMA Length')
src4 = close
out4 = ta.wma(src4, len4)
up4 = out4 > out4[1]
down4 = out4 < out4[1]
mycolor4 = up4 ? color.green : down4 ? color.red : color.blue
plot(out4 and wmaplot2 ? out4 : na, title='WMA', color=mycolor4, linewidth=2)

alertcondition(up1 and up3 and up4, title="Buy", message="green buy")
alertcondition(down1 and down3 and down4, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

With my script I receive an alert on all candles. Want only one alert until one MA change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this, but in my opinion the easiest one is checking if you are currently "all green" and not "all green" on previous bar. That way you won't get an alert if you are "all green" on current bar and not "all green" on previous bar:

```
buyCond = up1 and up3 and up4
sellCond = down1 and down3 and down4
alertcondition(buyCond and not buyCond[1], title="Buy", message="green buy")
alertcondition(sellCond and not sellCond[1], title="Sell", message="red sell")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I am testing it but does not seems to work as the condition was met but no alert.

Comment: I had a typo… forgot to add history referencing. I’ve edited the code. Should work now